# Zoom / enlarge user interface or fonts maya 2017

Tags: user-interface, zooming, maya

I need to enlarge Maya's UI as shown [here](https://knowledge.autodesk.com/support/maya/learn-explore/caas/CloudHelp/cloudhelp/2016/ENU/Maya/files/GUID-03BF2E0E-6FB1-438E-A238-3298994CFADB-htm.html) as the letters and fonts are way too small. The problem however is that this solution is based on 2016 version, a setting which, presumably, changed for the latest version.
How to do the same with v.2017?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fonts can be enlarged via modifying a script into the app's package.

If you are using Mac, go to

`/Applications/Autodesk/maya20xx/Maya.app/Contents/Resources`

If you are using Windows, go to

`C:\Program Files\Autodesk\Maya20xx\resources\MayaStrings`

(Where xx the version of your Maya copy)

You need to **backup first** and edit MayaStrings with an editor and go search and find

`// String set: s_TschemeResources`

and now all you have to do is to change the first number of font's size for your os (mac or win) accordingly. i.e.:

s_TschemeResources.rBoldLabelFont_mac = "13,1,0,0,0,0,Lucida Grande"
s_TschemeResources.rBoldLabelFont_win = "13,1,0,0,0,0,Tahoma"

Answer (score 0):

Not a global UI answer, but if you want to change the font of a particular UI element you can do it by applying a styleSheet to the specific element... as an example, this is what i use to set my script editor font preferences.

```
from PySide2 import QtWidgets

def set_script_editor_font(family   = 'Courier New', 
                           emphasis = 'normal', 
                           bg_color = 'normal',
                           size     = 12):
    
    """
    Usage: family:   The font's family, ex: Courier, Wingdings, etc...
           emphasis: The font's emphasis, ex: Bold, italic, etc... normal (default)
           bg_color: The font's background color, ex: black, white, etc... normal (default)
           size :    The font's size in pixels.
    """
    
    # find the MayaWindow widget
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication.instance()
    win = next(x for x in app.topLevelWidgets() if x.objectName()=='MayaWindow')

    # add a scriptEditor styleSheet to maya_ui
    win.setProperty('maya_ui', 'scriptEditor')
    styleSheet = '''
    QWidget[maya_ui="scriptEditor"] QTextEdit {
      font-family: "%s";
      font: %s %spx;
      background-color: %s;
    }
    ''' %(family, emphasis, size, bg_color)

    app.setStyleSheet(styleSheet)

    
# this is my current favorite
set_script_editor_font(family='Consolas', size=18) 

# use this if you code with a quill
set_script_editor_font(family='Lucida Handwriting')   

# use this if you're drunk
set_script_editor_font(family='Wingdings')
```